# Import XLIFF in Ektron

Tags: ektron, xliff

I am working in Ektron 8.0.

I have been trying to import XLIFF files to ektron through API.I made use of the following piece of code to achive this.

```
 private void ImportTranslation()
    {
        try
        {
            Ektron.Cms.LocalizationAPI m_objLocalizationApi = new Ektron.Cms.LocalizationAPI();
            m_objLocalizationApi.StartImportTranslation();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I called this function and i added the XLIFF file to the "uploadedfiles" directory programmatically.
I handled this code in a button click,and it works like a charm!
When i wrote this code in the Page_Load event in the workarea,in the status tree structure it shows
the following exception,
"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

I am supposed to handle the XLIFF Import in a webservice,it also results in throwing the same error.

Can anybody help me in resolving this?